# How to get from Excel STOCKHISTORY to a list in R?

Tags: r, excel, vba, dplyr

I need to find some historical time series for Stocks and have the result in R.
I tried already the package "quantmod", but unfortunately most of the stocks are not covered.
I found EXCELS "STOCKPRICEHISTORY" to yield good results.

Hence, to allow more solutions, I phrase my question more open:

How do I get from a table, that contains Stocks (Ticker), Startdate and Endate to a list in R which contains each respective stock and its stockprice timeseries?

My Startingpoint looks like this:

[image: Example of Data]

My aim at the very End is to have something like this:
(Its also ok if I have every single stock price timeseries as csv)

[image]

My ideas so far:

1. Excel VBA Solution - 1
   Write a macro, that executes EXCELS "STOCKHISTORY" function on each of these stocks, and writes them as csv or so? Then after that, read them in and create a list in R
2. Excel VBA Solution - 2
   Write a macro, that executes EXCELS "STOCKHISTORY" function on each of these stocks,
   each one in a new worksheet? Bad Idea, since there are more than 4000 Stocks..
3. R Solution
   (If possible) call "STOCKHISTORY" function from R directly (?)

Any suggestions on how to takle this?

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an API, especially over trying to connect to Excel via VBA. There are many that are free, but require and API key from their website. For example, alphavantage.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

symbol = "IBM"
av_key = "demo"

url <- str_c("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&amp;symbol=", symbol ,"&amp;apikey=", av_key, "&amp;datatype=csv")

d <- read_csv(url)

d %>% head
```

Cred and other options: https://quantnomad.com/2020/07/06/best-free-api-for-historical-stock-data-examples-in-r/

Comment: I'm coming from trying to use REFINITIVs data API, the issue there is that a huge amount of TICKER has to be translated into RICs (Reuters Security Identifier). While some follow a specific pattern, many are completely off... This is how I ended up, taking a look at EXCELs function... It also pulls data from REFINITIV, but is ok with simple Tickers...

Comment: Try a different API. Alphavantage accepts ticker symbols.

Comment: Just wanted to comment for people trying the same path: Alphavantage & any kind of path through yahoo finance (e.g. quantmod package) doesnt do the trick, as the stock information covered is mainly restricted to "mainstream" stocks. Here excels Stockhistory with its access to REFINITIV is much more powerful

Comment: Really it depends on the stock tickers you are interested in. I haven't tested the stock tickers in the image in the question, but if they don't work in Alphavantage, you may contact the sales team of other API providers to see if the stock coverage. Many stock APIs exist, and few are probably better than REFINITIV. https://towardsdatascience.com/best-5-free-stock-market-apis-in-2019-ad91dddec984

Comment: For other useres, having the same difficulty and having the need to convert Tickers to RIC - there is a thread in the REFINITIV Developer Forum (the answer unfortunately is beyond my programming skills) Edit: In case anyone could help me with this dm me https://community.developers.refinitiv.com/questions/84002/how-can-i-get-the-rics-for-a-list-of-tickers.html